# Enabling Vt-X in BIOS concerns

Tags: virtualbox, bios

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad with Windows 10 and I'm trying to develop an app in Android Studio. I need to enable VT-x in BIOS and I am a little scared that I'll mess up my computer.  In order to enable VT-x in BIOS I do have to change some PC firmware setting

I know that enabling VT-x in BIOS will allow me to run virtual machines, but it won't mess up my computer in any way?  I've heard of people who can't startup their computers upon changing firmware settings.

Comment: Yes;  In order to enable hardware virtualization, you have to enable it.  There isn't any other way.

Comment: "I've heard of people who can't startup their computers upon changing firmware settings." That's most likely changing **legacy (MBR)** mode to **UEFI (EFI)** or vice versa when you'll see that occuring. Nothing to do with virtualisation.

Answer (score 0):

> it won't mess up my computer in any way will it?

You don't really have a choice.  In order to enable hardware virtualization, you must enable the feature within the firmware settings.

> I've heard of people who can't startup their computers upon changing firmware settings.

Simply enabling hardware virtualization will not result in this state.  Without specific information on those cases, it is not possible to explain what happens to those other people.

Comment: To the user who is serial downvoting random answers.  You can stop, all your votes have been reversed, the only thing you will accomplish is to be permanently banned.

Comment: @JW0914 - Upvotes indicate the contribution is helpful.  I see more questions that have problems, and see upvotes, I don’t personally see the difference.  However, this discussion is out of scope, and is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Enabelling virtualization is as simple as entering your computer in BIOS at startup  and selecting enable virtualization make sure you press F10 to exit and save.

You won't really notice a difference unless you're planning to run virtual operating systems. Some computers come out of the box with virtualization enabled like my Dell Inspiron Rizen 5 3500u.

So don't stress if worse comes to worst and you're not happy with how your computer is running, just simply go back and turn it off.

All it does is makes a single processor operate as if it was multiple processors.